# Export *.exe with *.dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I Have a Solution, in this solution there are several projects.
One project (main project) output type is Windows application, so his releas is *.exe.
The other projects output type is Calss Libray so their releases are *.dll. 
I want to seperate the *.dll files from the *.exe file.

I mean, that the exe file will be in a seperate folder from the *.dll.

how i do so?

Comment: with all due respect but it sounds to me that you need a bit more basic knowledge about VS before asking.

Comment: You can put the DLLs anywhere you want.  The odds that the CLR will find them back are very slim however.  Why do you want to give it a hard time?  What you have to do to help it find them is called DLL Hell.

Comment: Do you have any reason for doing that? What do you want the directory structure to look like, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the output directory in the individual project properties within your solution. If these are separate projects I would expect them to be in separate directories by default.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165410(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is Visual Studio. Open the Properties for the project. In Configuration Properties | General | Output Directory, enter the folder you want.

You can also use variables like $(ConfigurationName).

Comment: When i do release on the main project, beacuse he have a references to all others project he make for them a *.dll in the same folder...

Comment: In the "Project Property Pages", there is a combo box named "Configuration". Did you set the correct folders for both Debug and Release configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the project properties, select the Build tab on the left, and change the value in the Output path text box. Note that this value is Configuration specific, so you will either need to change the Configuration to All Configurations before changing the value or you will need to change the value for each configuration.